# applying list of functions columns in data frame

Tags: r, apply

I have 2 variables, `a` and `b`. `a` is potentially very large. `b` is always a vector of functions that can be applied to each column in the data frame `a`.

```
a <- data.frame(col1=c(1, 2, 3), col2=c(4, 5, 6))
b <- c(as.double, function(x) {1+x})
```

So the result that I want is that function `b[1]` is applied to col1, `b[2]` is applied to col2, and so on for all columns. I feel lapply should be used here but documentation seems to say that it can only have one function. I could use a loop I suppose but a "vectorised" way would be nice.

Comment: Why do you need a loop?

Comment: I guess `mapply` could be of use. See something like `mapply(function(x, y) y(x), x = a, y = b)` perhaps

Comment: RScriv, I don't *need* a loop per se, I meant it could be done that way (for each column, get the corresponding indexed function in b and apply) - but as I said would much prefer a vectorized approach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one way to do it:

```
results <- mapply(function(i,j) b[[i]](a[[j]]), i=1:length(b), j=1:length(a))
```

It gives you:

```
> results
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    5
[2,]    2    6
[3,]    3    7
```